# Use Signalr in SharePoint 2013 Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, signalr, sharepoint-2013, owin

We need to build a web-part for SharePoint 2013 which use Signalr. I know that it is easy to make it using app-part but in my case I need it in a web-part. I didn't find any article about that

To do this, I followed the setup steps for Signalr on ASP.NET to add it to the SharePoint project as following:

1. Add the required scripts (Signalr.js and JQuery.js) to Layout folder
2. Add reference to these files to My web-part like

`

```
 <script src="/_layouts/15/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
 <script src="/_layouts/15/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

`

3. Define Hub class contains one test method
4. Add startup class as following

`

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Notifications.Code.OWINStartup))]

namespace Notifications.Code
{

    public class OWINStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

`

My problem is in the last point, Owin is not started up and this made hub proxy file "/Signalr/hubs" file not found

Any help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution [here](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/531740):

OWIN use HttpHandler called OwinHttpHandler in the assembly Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb to start. This not work on my SharePoint server as IIS machine.config doesn't contain this handler so I added it to my website web.config as following

```
<add name="Owin" verb="*" path="/signalr" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Note: Don't forget to change assembly version according the version you have on your server

**You can read compelete steps to make Signalr work on SharePoint web-part [here](http://mohamedramadanahmed.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/use-signalr-with-sharepoint-webparts/)**